# Combine Two Shader Program

Tags: opengl, android, shaders, andengine, fragment-shader

For my android application, I want to apply brightness and contrast shader on same image.

At present I am using [gpuimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)  plugin. In that I found two separate program for brightness and contrast as per the following.

Contrast shader:

```
    varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
    uniform lowp float contrast;

    void main()
    {
         lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

         gl_FragColor = vec4(((textureColor.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5)), textureColor.w);
    }
```

Brightness shader:

```
    varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
    uniform lowp float brightness;

    void main()
    {
        lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

        gl_FragColor = vec4((textureColor.rgb + vec3(brightness)), textureColor.w);
    }
```

Now applying both of the effects I write following code

```
    varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
    varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;
    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
    uniform lowp float contrast;
    uniform lowp float brightness;

    void main()
    {
        lowp vec4 textureColorForContrast = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

        lowp vec4 contastVec4 = vec4(((textureColorForContrast.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5)), textureColorForContrast.w);
        lowp vec4 textureColorForBrightness = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

        lowp vec4 brightnessVec4 = vec4((textureColorForBrightness.rgb + vec3(brightness)), textureColorForBrightness.w);
        gl_FragColor = contastVec4 + brightnessVec4;
    }
```

Doesn't able to get desire result. I can't able to figure out what I have to do next? So please friends help me in this. What program I have to write?

Comment: This question is a [intra-network cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189162/combine-two-shader-program). Please don't cross-post between StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform lowp float brightness;
uniform lowp float contrast;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    textureColor.rgb = ((textureColor.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5));
    gl_FragColor = vec4((textureColor.rgb + vec3(brightness)), textureColor.w);
}
```

EDIT:
The reason why your shader was not working, is because you were doubling the input too. If you think of it, the first shaders apply **ONE effect to ONE image**. When merging both, you'd expect **TWO effects on ONE image**. But what you tried to do was applying **TWO effects on TWO images**. You just had to get rid of the second texture and UV parameters, then apply both effects on the single texture remaining.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: Sorry at present I can't give you reply because my eclipse not working properly because adt update and it frustrating me.

Comment: your answer is correct and worked as expected. thanks for help